# horn fuse blows after charging the battery

Tags: vw, fuse, horn

I have this interesting problem with my Volkswagen Polo 6R: right after i recharged my Car Battery the fuse of the horn blows. It is happening when i start the car. If I replace the fuse it will blow in the next 2-3 times when i start my car. Before starting it the horn is useable and the fuse is not even blowing when  i use it.

I had this problem in the past and already replaced the horn. All went fine but since i changed the battery this problem comes up again.

I have no clue why this is happening and i dont want to switch my horn always when i recharge my battery.

Thanks in advance :)